# How to print the following JSON to pretty format?

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
{ "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" },
{ "firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith" },
{ "firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones" }
```

This is my sample JSON, not having root tag. How can I take the whole JSON and iterate over it for each line and store it as a String object in Java and parse as a JSON Object? I tried this code.

```
String file = "D:\\employees.json";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String data = "";

        data = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file)));
        System.out.println(data);
        Object json = mapper.readValue(data, employees.class);
        System.out.println("JSON -> "+json);
        String indented = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(json);
        System.out.println(indented);
```

But here the json variable is holding only single row of the file, but I want the entire file to be printed in pretty format. How can I do that ? Here every line is a separate entity.

Comment: You have not valid JSON

Comment: if you have the comma between the lines like in the sample, you can just wrap your String in `[ ]` to get valid JSON.

Comment: Since the data is already in a file, you can also have `jq` work on that file, it understands the "one-JSON-per-line" format.

Comment: @vlad324: I have the JSON file like this only. I dont have the root tags in the file. I have to separate it for every line and take it as different object and parse it to JSON.

Comment: @Thilo But that will not be the pretty format.

Comment: Why not? Once it is valid JSON, you can send it through Jackson to make it pretty. (But do try `jq`, no need to write your own code for this)

Comment: @SayanSahoo so if you have parsed every line of JSON separately, you should have `List<Emploee>` that you can serialize with `PrettyPrinter`

Answer (score 1):

Based on you answers in comments, I think it should work:

```
String file = "here file path";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<Object> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file))) {
    employeeList.add(mapper.readValue(line, Object.class));
}

String indented = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(employeeList);
System.out.println(indented);
```

Output JSON looks like this:

```
[ {
  "firstName" : "John",
  "lastName" : "Doe"
}, {
  "firstName" : "Anna",
  "lastName" : "Smith"
}, {
  "firstName" : "Peter",
  "lastName" : "Jones"
} ]
```

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input

It is showing this exception while adding it in the arraylist.

Comment: can you debug it and find for which line of file it throw this exception?

Comment: employeeList.add(mapper.readValue(line, Object.class));

In this line I have the issue.

Comment: I mean not line of code, but line of input file, because the line that you pointed is inside for-each cycle, that iterate over input file lines

Comment: The loop is not even iterating for a single time, at first iteration only it is crashing.